# Unable to stream ogg local files to webview using custom NetworkAccessManager

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtwebkit, qtnetwork

I have been investigating this issue but I'm mostly stucked, I'm writing a custom music player using python, pyqt and pywebkit. The case is that I can play .mp3 files or even .wav files without any problem, but ogg files never get reached.

Example code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys,gtk,webkit,os,json,re,base64,urllib2,sqlite3,math,time,Queue,mimetypes,subprocess
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit, QtNetwork
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl

class NetworkAccessManager(QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self, parent)

    def createRequest(self,operation,request,outgoingData):
        url = unicode(request.url().toString())

        if url.startswith('http://mycustomprotocol') :
            localFile = url[24:];
            print localFile
            request.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile(localFile))

        reply = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self,operation,request,outgoingData)
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('networkRequestCreated(QNetworkReply*)'),reply)
        print 'createRequest',url,operation
        #self.connect(reply, QtCore.SIGNAL('downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)'), self.foo)
        return reply

    def foo(self, *args):
        print args

class Browser(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    # Ventana del programa
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser,self).__init__(None)

        self.tabWidget = QtGui.QTabWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabWidget)

        self.webview = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        self.n = NetworkAccessManager(self);
        self.webview.page().setNetworkAccessManager(self.n)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.tabWidget.addTab(self.webview,'loading...'))
        #self.webview.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("index.html"))
        self.webview.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("/home/marcos/Descargas/examp/index.html"))

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    browser = Browser()
    browser.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

index.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <div><audio src='http://mycustomprotocol/1.mp3' controls=true/></div>
    asd
    <div><audio src='http://mycustomprotocol/1.ogg' controls=true/></div>
    asd
    <div><audio src='http://mycustomprotocol/1.wav' controls=true/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

You only need to fill the folder with the different types of audio files (note the index.html path in the loading webview URL is absolute, couldnt make the example to work with relative). Resources to test:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Example.ogg

http ://audio.online-convert.com/convert-to-wav

find google "filetype:mp3"

You will see that the audio mp3 is playing quite well, the wav too, but the ogg file strangely wont play. If you point the webview to the URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Example.ogg you will be able to play that ogg file, and the page html5test says webview have vorvis audio support. But again unable to play through NetworkAccessManager, Im a bit lost, please, give me some hints